# Best selling product - Get price?

Tags: price

I'm adding a best selling products block to my sidebar, but I have encountered a problem.
I simply cannot get the price of the product.

Here is my template;

```
<?php

$totalPerPage = ($this->show_total) ? $this->show_total : 6;
$counter = 1;
$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                              ->addOrderedQty()
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
                              ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
?>

<div class="content-box-header">Bestsellers</div>
<div class="content-box">
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $product): ?>


<?php if($counter <= $totalPerPage): ?>

<?php $productUrl =  $product->getProductUrl() ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $productUrl ?>" title="View <?php echo $product->name ?>">
    <h4><?php echo $product->name ?></h4>
  </a>

  <a href="<?php echo $productUrl ?>" title="View <?php echo $product->name ?>">
  <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(120); ?>" alt="Product image"  />
  </a> <br />
  <p><?php echo $product->short_description ?></p>


<?php endif; $counter++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

On the 4th line from the bottom I want to display the price instead of the short describtion.
I've tried replacing it with;

```
$_product->getPrice()
```

But that made the sidebar crash. What should I insert instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this code of yours at my root like this, and it worked for me, only issue that came up was in the image so I replaced your image code with mine:

```
<?php

$magePath = 'app/Mage.php'; 

require_once $magePath;

Varien_Profiler::enable(); 

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
$totalPerPage = 6;
$counter = 1;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                              ->addOrderedQty()
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
                              ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
                              ?>
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $product): ?>


<?php if($counter <= $totalPerPage): ?>

<?php $productUrl =  $product->getProductUrl() ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $productUrl ?>" title="View <?php echo $product->name ?>">
    <h4><?php echo $product->name ?></h4>
  </a>

  <a href="<?php echo $productUrl ?>" title="View <?php echo $product->name ?>">
  <?php $product_image_url = $product->getImageUrl(); ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $product_image_url; ?>" alt="Product image"  />
  </a> <br />
  <p><?php echo $product->short_description ?></p>
<?php echo $product->getPrice(); ?>

<?php endif; $counter++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```